# AngularJS custom directive with dynamic data in link function on an element

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a custom directive, where i want to append the template within the link function for an element. The content is coming up fine if there are no angular expressions/attributes. But when i add angular expressions/attributes, the UI is getting rendered as objects on browser like [[object HTMLDivElement], [object HTMLButtonElement]]. Please let me know how to compile the dynamic data added in the custom directive

HTML:

```
{{message}}
<user-address></user-address>
```

JS:

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);
module.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
$scope.User = 'Manju';
$scope.fnAddNewAddress = function () {
    $scope.message = 'New address added';
}
});

module.directive('userAddress', function ($compile) {
var directive = {};
directive.link = function (scope, element) {
    var template = '<div>Please find below the address of the user {{user}}</div><button ng-click="fnAddNewAddress()">Add address</button>';
    var lnkFn = $compile(template);
    var content = lnkFn(scope);
    element.html(content);
}
return directive;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it, what i'm missing here. I should be using element.append instead of element.html with in the link function